# Angular 6 open select programmatically

Tags: drop-down-menu, angular6

I'm trying to open select option using javascript in angular 6

```
const dropDown = document.getElementById(id);
    let event;
    event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
    dropDown.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Also tried like

```
@ViewChild('select') select: ElementRef;
func() {
   this.select.nativeElement.open();
}
```

but it is not working. I have searched and found results for material and for ionic. But how can I open in angular 6?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible, but you can achieve this by setting the size of the select and having it float using position:absolute.

```
<div  style="position:relative">.<select style="position:absolute;top:-8px;left:-20px" onClick="onAssign(this)">   
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select></div>

function openMySelect(){
  document.querySelector(‘#mySelect’).size=YOUR_OPTIONS.length;
}

function onAssign(data,select){
  select.size=1
  // your logic
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, also the syntax is invalid.

Comment: Did you mean the .size syntax?  I corrected it now. Thank you.  So this works for me.  What is not working for your project?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this on an angular app using

`document.getElementById('shippingRates').click()`

If you're doing some model updates in your app just before you expect the drop down to be opened, then consider delaying this call with something like

`window.setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('shippingRates').click(), 100);`

Answer (score -3):

```
    @ViewChild('select') select: ElementRef;
func() {
   this.select.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Use focus() it will work.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, select element is only focused, not opened.